# CSS how to have two divs to the right of one div but not beside each other

Tags: html, css

I have three divs background-color Red, Yellow and Blue. I am wanting to get the Red div on the left. I want the Yellow div beside the Red. I want the Blue div beside the Red but underneath the Yellow div. 
I came up with

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div style="background-color:Red; height:50%; float: left">Red</div>
          <div style="background-color:Yellow; float: left; clear:right">Yellow</div>
          <div style="background-color:Blue; float:left">Blue</div>
     </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work however as the Blue div is not underneath the Yellow div but beside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap them in `<div>`s to get columns:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red">
        Red
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="yellow">
        Yellow
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        Blue
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aNVam/

If you have specific sizes on your `<div>`s (or at least on the red one), you can do it without the wrappers using a `clear: left` and `margin-left` on the blue one:

```
<div class="red">
    Red
</div>
<div class="yellow">
    Yellow
</div>
<div class="blue">
    Blue
</div>
```

And the CSS for this one:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: 100px; /* see .red */
}
```

And a live example of this version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/t8mMt/1/

At least I think that's the layout you're after.

Comment: @mu... +1 we have the same solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left;` from the yellow and blue divs, i.e.:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div style="background-color:Red; height:50%; float: left">Red</div>
          <div style="background-color:Yellow;  clear:right">Yellow</div>
          <div style="background-color:Blue; ">Blue</div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think CSS positioning is what your looking for

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: There are several ways to do this, positioning is just an option. And PS, I believe in order to conform to W3 standards, you must have your styling done in a file or within the head tags

Comment: And not use W3Schools, a company not affiliated with W3 in any way ;)

Comment: well, if someone is having trouble with css, w3schools isn't the worst place to start, haha

Comment: True, true. There are *much* worse services available, no doubt. But speaking of layout, W3Schools uses a `<table>` based layout *and* depreciated HTML tags. I cried when I saw them...

Comment: I'd like to know what's wrong with w3schools? I thought it was most helpful as a beginner.